# spring-boot services are going down frequently

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, angular6

We have angular6 project with spring-boot services running locally and server as well, we have layer of activemq as well, we have seen that if we don't touch the services or angular 6 application for sometime, the locally deplyoed mock services are giving error as below:

2019-05-15 10:19:07.131  INFO [my-service,,,] 70992 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration.

This works well on server deployed microservices.
Do we need to increase any time period for activemq ?

Comment: Which error? That is just an info message.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an info message. The Eureka client sends a heartbeat every so often to the Eureka server and that is where that is coming from.
It is coming from here
[EurekaHttpClients](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/4f24d9dcf90713b421f6c092fa63e707cbf74df3/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/discovery/shared/transport/EurekaHttpClients.java#L133)

You should be able to control the interval by setting `eureka.client.eurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds`.